# WSS4J SHA1 value different when using IBM JDK 7 versus Oracle JDK 7

Tags: wss4j

I need help understanding why I am getting a different SHA1 digest value when using IBM JDK 7 versus Oracle JDK 7 along with the WSS4J library.

What I am trying to do now is force the use of Sun JCE, having moved Sun JARs to my IBM JDK. The reason is because my digest values are coming out right using Oracle JDK 7 and the digest values match the IRS's web service's calculation of them.

I am using canonicalization (C14N_EXCL_WITH_COMMENTS) in my code. But I am getting a different SHA1 hash for a an XML element when using IBM JDK 7 versus Oracle JDK 7. The XML that I am calculating a hash value for only has constants in it. Nothing changes in the below XML but I get different hash values:

```
    <urn:ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl
        xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
        wsu:Id="aCATransmitterManifestReqDtl">
        <urn:PaymentYr>2015</urn:PaymentYr>
        <urn:PriorYearDataInd>0</urn:PriorYearDataInd>
        <urn:TransmissionTypeCd>O</urn:TransmissionTypeCd>
        <urn:TestFileCd>T</urn:TestFileCd>
    </urn:ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl>
```

I am getting a different SHA1 value with the following code:

```
    WSSecSignature wsSecSignature = new WSSecSignature(config);

    wsSecSignature.setX509Certificate(signingCert);
    wsSecSignature.setUserInfo(alias, new String(keystorePassword.toCharArray()));
    wsSecSignature.setUseSingleCertificate(true);
    wsSecSignature.setKeyIdentifierType(WSConstants.X509_KEY_IDENTIFIER);
    wsSecSignature.setDigestAlgo(WSConstants.SHA1);
    wsSecSignature.setSignatureAlgorithm(WSConstants.RSA_SHA1);
    wsSecSignature.setSigCanonicalization(WSConstants.C14N_EXCL_WITH_COMMENTS);

    try {
        Document document = toDocument(message);
        WSSecHeader secHeader = new WSSecHeader();
        //secHeader.setMustUnderstand(true);
        secHeader.insertSecurityHeader(document);

        WSSecTimestamp timestamp = new WSSecTimestamp();            
        timestamp.setTimeToLive(signatureValidityTime);
        document = timestamp.build(document, secHeader);

        List<WSEncryptionPart> wsEncryptionParts = new ArrayList<WSEncryptionPart>();
        WSEncryptionPart timestampPart = new WSEncryptionPart("Timestamp",
                WSConstants.WSU_NS, "");

        WSEncryptionPart aCATransmitterManifestReqDtlPart = new WSEncryptionPart(
                "ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl",
                "urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0", "");
        WSEncryptionPart aCABusinessHeaderPart = new WSEncryptionPart(
                "ACABusinessHeader",
                "urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acabusinessheader", "");
        wsEncryptionParts.add(timestampPart);
        wsEncryptionParts.add(aCATransmitterManifestReqDtlPart);
        wsEncryptionParts.add(aCABusinessHeaderPart);
        wsSecSignature.setParts(wsEncryptionParts);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider",
                "org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
        Crypto crypto = CryptoFactory.getInstance(properties);
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
```

***EDIT WHAT I'VE TRIED, LOOKING FOR HELP FORCING PROVIDER TO BE SUN JCE***

I was hoping to enter the following code Provider sunJCE = Security.getProvider("SunJCE") ***but it is coming back null***

I edit my java.security file to include the sun.security.provider.SunJCE:

```
security.provider.1=com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2
security.provider.2=com.ibm.crypto.provider.IBMJCE
security.provider.3=com.ibm.security.jgss.IBMJGSSProvider
security.provider.4=com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPath
security.provider.5=com.ibm.security.sasl.IBMSASL
security.provider.6=com.ibm.xml.crypto.IBMXMLCryptoProvider
security.provider.7=com.ibm.xml.enc.IBMXMLEncProvider
security.provider.8=com.ibm.security.jgss.mech.spnego.IBMSPNEGO
security.provider.9=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.10=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.11=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.12=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.13=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
```

And I am programmatically trying to use the SunJCE as follows:

```
        Provider sunJCE = Security.getProvider("SunJCE");
        if (sunJCE != null) {
            logger.info("SunJCE Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) to provide cryptographic, key and hash algorithms : IBMJCE will be removed");

            try {
                Security.removeProvider("IBMJCE");
                Security.insertProviderAt(sunJCE, 1);
            } catch (SecurityException se) {
                logger.info("Cannot move SunJCE to top priority", se);
            }
        }
```

I also moved these JARs from Oracle JDK 7 to IBM JDK 7: (1) copied the sunjce_provider.jar jar file in to WAS_HOME/java/jre/lib/ext 
folder and (2) copied the jce.jar file in to was_home/java/jre/lib

Comment: What's your hardware and OS?

Comment: This code is  run from a Windows 7 Professional 64 bit OS. And the hardware is Intel i7 and 16Gb RAM.